# Dynamic/generic/custom forms in Java web app

Tags: java, struts

In our manufacturing process, we have many different forms out there that the workers have to fill out. We're trying to automate them. Instead of me coding up each form, I'd like to have it so that the workers define all of these forms and then we display/render them as necessary within our existing web app. I could code this all up myself, but I wouldn't mind finding some library that already does this. This is a Java web app using Struts.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have defined set of fields or not?

Comment: No. Each form will have its own set of fields. There could be a hundred forms, some added to the system in the future. More specifically, there could be Inspection Form A with one set of fields and then Inspection Form B with a completely different set of fields.

Comment: I don't know of anything that does this, although it's pretty trivial.

Comment: Yeah, codding it yourself much work. I don't know may be xforms will be an alternative.

Comment: It could be fairly trivial to code, depending on how complex the forms are going to be. What I'm thinking of right now is to give them the same flexibility as an HTML table.